# Symfony2 and date_default_timezone_get() in appkernel doesnot change

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting this error

I tried to change write this function in app/appkernel.php

```
public function init()
{
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Berlin' );
    parent::init();
}
```

i have also tried with __construct method but it still doesnot work.

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
}
```

But i still get this error... I cannt make changes to php.ini file as I am on virtual host and they dont allow

[Error screen shot](http://tinypic.com/r/1190zmw/8)

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: I cleared the cache many times... and now i am getting new error  Notice: Object of class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference could not be converted to int

Answer (score 0):

Add this into the index.php file in the root of `symfony2`:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Comment: I dont see index.php in symfony2 folder... do I need to create one..??

Comment: add it into the first root php file .a file that loads whole of the framework

Comment: I think you meant `app.php`.